# StartActivity doesnt work after process is killed

Tags: android, android-activity, process, fragment, lifecycle

I got a little problem with my app and I hope you could help me.

I developed an android app which contains an activity with fragment container which by default contains a pageviewer and through a navigation bar you can populate some more fragments.

In each of the fragments there are items, and when you click them they start a new activity.

Everything is working great until I drive my app into a state that the android OS kills its process for other apps, as described in the picture :
[image]

After I return to the app the listview is working fine, however when I click an item the new activity doesnt start, and the application just stays on the same page and for some reason OnResume() is called.
I check with debug messages and the OnClick function is working and the intent looks exactly like before the process kill.

Moreover, if I navigate to a new fragment everything is working fine.

Hope someone has the answer,
Thanks

Comment: Could you share some code please? Starting a new activity, intent creation & flags, activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I think I found the problem. If there I have a singleton in my application, which hold data, when the process is killed - it gets deleted?

Comment: If the process is killed, everything that is in RAM gets deleted. So, yes, your singleton will no longer be in memory.